# How to Pass data with onclickListener to other fragment in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am retrieving `Cloud Firestore` data in `Modelo.class` and I'm trying to pass these variables from the to fragment `DescDenuncia` using a adapter `Adapter.class` but to do that I need to get the context tfor it using the I've already tried use `AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();`, but my app crashes every time I run this line, and is necessary to use a Context in the getSupportFragmentManager() to it works. If i'm doing this in a wrong way please tell me I truly don't know what I should do, please someone answer me

I'm using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgfNl541oso&t=2449s

Modelo.java

```
package com.example.safe;

public class Modelo {

    String empresa, area, setor, tipo, risco, img, data, prazo, desc, resolucao, ID;

    public Modelo() {
    }


    public Modelo(String empresa, String area, String setor, String tipo, String risco, String img, String data, String prazo, String desc, String resolucao, String ID) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.area = area;
        this.setor = setor;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.risco = risco;
        this.img = img;
        this.data = data;
        this.prazo = prazo;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.resolucao = resolucao;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getSetor() {
        return setor;
    }

    public void setSetor(String setor) {
        this.setor = setor;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getRisco() {
        return risco;
    }

    public void setRisco(String risco) {
        this.risco = risco;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getPrazo() {
        return prazo;
    }

    public void setPrazo(String prazo) {
        this.prazo = prazo;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getResolucao() {
        return resolucao;
    }

    public void setResolucao(String resolucao) {
        this.resolucao = resolucao;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Home.java

```
package com.example.safe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    RecyclerView recview;
    Adapter adapter;


    public static Home newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Home fragment = new Home();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;

    }

    public Home() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recview = view.findViewById(R.id.rvDenuncias);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Ocorrencias")
                .limit(50);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Modelo> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Modelo>()
                .setQuery(query, Modelo.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new Adapter(options);
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
package com.example.safe;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

//Vinculando o reclycler view ao firestore
public class Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Modelo, Adapter.myviewholder> {


    public Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Modelo> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    //Sobrescrevendo o método
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Modelo model) {
        //Associando os itens do atalho ocorrências
        holder.IDText.setText(model.getID());
        holder.tipoText.setText(model.getTipo());
        Glide.with(holder.img1.getContext()).load(model.getImg()).into(holder.img1);

        //Ação de entrar abrir a ocorrência
        holder.RLAYOUT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////THE PROBLEM IS HERE///////////////////////////////////////////
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new DescDenuncia(
                        //importando as variáveis do Modelo e enviado para o DescDenun
                        model.getEmpresa(),
                        model.getArea(),
                        model.getSetor(),
                        model.getTipo(),
                        model.getRisco(),
                        model.getImg(),
                        model.getData(),
                        model.getPrazo(),
                        model.getDesc(),
                        model.getResolucao(),
                        model.getID()
                        )).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.modelo_atalho_ocorrencias, parent, false);
        return new myviewholder(view);

    }

    //Coneção do reclycler view com essa classe
    public class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //Variáveis do modelo atalho
        TextView tipoText, IDText;
        RelativeLayout RLAYOUT;
        ImageView img1;

        //Associando os objetos ao modelo atalho
        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            tipoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipo);
            img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            IDText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModeloID);
            RLAYOUT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RLlayout);
        }

    }
}
```

DescDenuncia.java

```
package com.example.safe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class DescDenuncia extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    String empresa, area, setor, tipo, risco, img, data, prazo, desc, resolucao, ID;
    ImageButton bt_Voltar, bt_Manutencao;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public DescDenuncia() {

    }

    public DescDenuncia(String empresa, String area, String setor, String tipo, String risco, String img, String data, String prazo, String desc, String resolucao, String ID) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.area = area;
        this.setor = setor;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.risco = risco;
        this.img = img;
        this.data = data;
        this.prazo = prazo;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.resolucao = resolucao;
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public static DescDenuncia newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DescDenuncia fragment = new DescDenuncia();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_desc_denuncia, container, false);


        TextView EmprHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunEmpr);
        TextView AreaHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunArea);
        TextView SetorHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunSetor);
        TextView TipoHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunTipo);
        TextView RiscoHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunRisco);
        ImageView ImgDenun = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunImg);
        TextView DataHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunData);
        TextView PrazoHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDenunPrazo);
        TextView DescHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
        TextView ResolHolder = view.findViewById(R.id.txtFeedback);

        //Definindo os as variáveis para o valor
        EmprHolder.setText(empresa);
        AreaHolder.setText(area);
        SetorHolder.setText(setor);
        TipoHolder.setText(tipo);
        RiscoHolder.setText(risco);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(img).into(ImgDenun);
        DataHolder.setText(data);
        PrazoHolder.setText(prazo);
        DescHolder.setText(desc);
        ResolHolder.setText(resolucao);


        return view;
    }

    public void onBackPressed()
    {

        AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)getContext();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,new Home()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
}
```